# Existe algum banco de dados gratuito para código de barras de produto?

Tags: banco-de-dados, web-service, código-de-barras

Estou fazendo um aplicativo que está relacionado a produtos de supermercado, e uma possibilidade futura é que, ao invés do usuário pesquisar por nome o produto, ele possa também usar o celular para escanear o código de barras.

Como posso relacionar o código de barras com o produto?

Tem algum banco de dados, gratuito ou não, que, dado um código de barras, me retorne seu produto associado?

Comment: Chegou a ver este site? http://www.gs1br.org/

Comment: http://www.afrac.org.br/index.php  ... estou fora do varejo faz tempo mas era a associação que cuidava disto.

Comment: @brasofilo o problema aí pelo o que parece é que esse site que vc indicou para ter acesso a pessoa tem de associar-se e parece que tem-se uma taxa a pagar.
Mas já é um começo, por isso dei +1 pro seu comentário :)

Comment: Pois é, eu até tinha visto esse gs1br, mas pelo jeito é pago. Bom, acho que o jeito será cadastrar os códigos de barra um por um eu mesmo...